# Illustrator: how to mimic a vignette dot pattern filling irregular shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a map graphic, and I'd like to create an effect for sandy shoals, such as you see on this image. By default, I could just have the outline as a heavier dot, and the fill as a tile using smaller dots. But I'd love to be able to mimic the vignette effect that appears on this hand drawn map. Suggestions? Thanks[image]

Comment: I'm looking forward to answers to this. I believe this effect is sometimes called *stipple* effect. Afaik there is no simple way to achieve this out of the box. Perhaps the [Stipplism plugin from Astute Graphics](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/stipplism) could be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

## Option A - A Plug in.

I, personally, would make my life easier and use the **Phantasm** plug in from [AstuteGraphics.com](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/phantasm). It's not a free plug in, but for me, it's worth the expense specifically because it does many things in 5 minutes that would otherwise take hours to try and create.

Start with a basic shape that's a gradient mesh.. dark edges, lighter center....

[image]

(You can use non-mesh objects as well. But for this example the mesh works better).

Then choose `Effects > Phantasm > Halftone` to bring up the Phantasm window...

[image]
<sub>(CS6 screenshot)</sub>

What this does is use values to determine the size of halftone dots/characters. The darker the value, the larger the dot.

From there it's merely a matter of adjusting the settings in the window....

[image]

---

You can also adjust the curves in the dialog window to refine the appearance....

[image]

I believe there's a free trial available at Astute's site. That may suffice for a single project.

You can leave the effect as "live" to adjust further later, or expand it so it's "baked in" in case you need to adjust manually.

---

Quite honestly getting gradient meshes correct on irregular shapes will be more difficult that any of the plug in adjusting.

---

<sub>Disclosure: 
In the past, Astute Graphics *has* provided me with free software in exchange for my evaluation and opinion. 
However, I do *not* benefit in any way should another user choose to purchase Astute products.</sub>

---

## Option 2 - A Blend

Two dotted strokes.. blended...

[image]

This provides the decrease in dots, but everything remains rather uniform otherwise. This *could* be accomplished with blends, but things would probably need sectioning to get the drop off correct. I didn't spend any real time on this blend.. so it leave much to be desired.

Comment: I may try this....thanks. I did suspect it would involve a halftone type of effect, but couldn't see how it could be done to fit an irregular shape!

Comment: Nice answer, but I still think there is a long way from halftones to the more organic stipple dithering. You go quickly through the *Pattern* options, so I can't really get a good look at the *FM* and *Radial* settings. Do you have the whole Astute package? Could *Stipplism* be of any use? I'm asking because I'm interested in a more organic way of dithering where the dots doesn't follow a regular pattern. A bit like [this](https://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/images/IP_Halftoning_stippling.png).

Comment: @Wolff Stiplism is a CC2019+ pug in I believe.. Astute dropped CS6 dev a year or so ago. I *might* have it.. but booted for AI CS6 at the moment (like most of the time) and can't access AICC(bleeding edge) at this time. So, I can't say directly. Phantasm tends to create more uniformity overall.

Comment: I *think* Stiplism is merely this Phantasm Halftone effect + scatter options... (Phantasm has no scatter options)

Comment: @Scott, I've been playing around with [a script](http://madswolff.dk/projects/Stippler/) which can make this stippling effect based on 2D ball collision. I like the result, but sadly it's very slow. On my computer it takes about 70 seconds before an svg file is ready for download.